# How do I count how many times a user has logged in in a row in PHP

Tags: php

I am just getting back into PHP after about 7 years away so am very rusty.

I am wanting to add a feature to my site whereby it tracks the users logins daily and then prints their logins visually on the website. I want it to record consecutive logins and when the user misses a day, return the value to zero.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: what kind of help do you need?

Comment: This question is too broad to be on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a `consecutiveDayCounter` and a `lastDayConnected` row in your user table.

In your `SELECT` query to check if the user and password matches, you should also SELECT these row.
Verify if lastDayConnected == than yesterday timestamp.

Then, do an `UPDATE` query with today timestamp for the `lastDayConnected` , and if the check for lastDayConnected == yesterday timestamp,  add +1 to `consecutiveDayCounter`. If not, update it to 0.

EDIT :

As asked, here's some example code to get today - yesterday stamp :

```
<?php
// Today
$today = new DateTime();                 // Create new date object (today date)
echo $today->format('Y-m-d');            // Format the date 'YYYY-MM-DD'


// Yesterday 
$yesterday = new DateTime();               // Create new date object (today date)
$yesterday->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));  // Substract 1 day to it
echo $yesterday->format('Y-m-d');          //Format the date 'YYYY-MM-DD'
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure on how to use time-stamps correctly, could you give me some example code please?

Comment: @AidenTaylor Sure, I edited my post for some example code to get the time-stamp

Comment: Thanks so much @SamyQc, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @AidenTaylor No problem, hope it helped ! Mark my answer as accepted if it resolved your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Remember (e.g. in database) number of login attempts and time of the last login attempt.

If the date of the last login attempt is today, use the count from database. Otherwise consider the count to be zero.

Once the user logs in, remember the time and add 1 to the count calculated as described.